# execl() command in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to include a file using execl() and submit the whole thing as an assignment could any one please help me what are the parameters that I can use in this.. can I send any other parameters other than the file path and the file name.

Comment: Using `excel()`? You mean Microsoft Excel? That requires a license, and thus isn't compatible with Linux.

Comment: No it is execl() command in linux.

Comment: Other than file path you can send as many parameters you wish.   
But the last parameter to execl() must be NULL in order to indicate  
the end of parameter list.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve.  Apparently, you want to write a C program that uses the [`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html) _function_ (not _command_!) to execute some other program that will read a file — but it is not clear where you want the contents of the file to go to.  Nor is it clear where the file name is coming from; will it be an argument to the program you write, or built in?  Have you considered using `cat` instead of your program?  Have you considered having your program use `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

Before using execl you must know that the process created by using execl() overwrites the
context of the process which makes the call to execl(). Thus we use a child process to
invoke another process so that the parent can continue its useful work.

General syntax for the execl() call :

```
return_value = execl(arg1, arg2, arg3......., NULL);
```

return_value is -1 if execl fails, and this function returns only when it fails.

arg1 : conventionally this argument is supposed to be the file path.
arg2 : Name of the file.
arg3 : Can be any thing in string format.

Note : All the arguments to the execl() are of type "const char *" i.e. immutable
strings. (string whose values must not be changed, else gives error.)

Comment: Will the file which is imported by execl will create a run time file?

Comment: No ! It will not "create" the file. The file should be present when  
when execl is invoked.
execl just creates a new process not file.